# How to Select all child elements of a given Node in SqlHierarchyId?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a Node as **`/1/2/`**, Here I want to select all child Nodes of **`'/1/2/'`**
Ex **`/1/2/1/`** , **`/1/2/2/1/.../`**

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to look at [`IsDescendantOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677203.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A worked example of what Mark's talking about, using [IsDescendantOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677203.aspx):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( hId hierarchyId PRIMARY KEY )

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
    ( '/1/' ),
    ( '/1/2/' ),
    ( '/1/2/1/' ),
    ( '/1/2/2/1/' ),
    ( '/3/' ),
    ( '/3/4/' )

DECLARE @hId hierarchyId = '/1/2/'

SELECT *, hId.ToString() hId_string
FROM @t
WHERE hId.IsDescendantOf(@hId) = 1
```